# Не удаляется фотография, загруженная через cms

Tags: wordpress

столкнулся с очень интересной проблемой касающейся фотографии.

Есть фотография image-7, я ее удалил через медиафайлы в вордпрессе, но переходя по ссылке https://site/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/image-7.png
фотография все равно открывается.

Подключился через FTP, перешел по пути /wp-content/uploads/2020/12/ но фотографии я этой там не обнаружил.

Все фотографии хранятся именно в этой папке. Собственно вопрос, в чем же может быть проблема?
Как так получилось, что удалив фотографию я все равно могу ее открыть по ссылке и почему в таком случае в корне сайта её нету?

Comment: Возможно у вас на сайте используется cdn, например Cloudflare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть она у вас просто сохранилась в кэше? Очистите кэш и обновите страницу.